# What is the problem in my laravel-vue code?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am new in vue, I installed vue in my laravel project. but the problem is there when I call a new route it does not work and not display the wanted result.
this is my app.js code:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import router from "./router";
Vue.component('mainapp',require('./components/mainApp').default);
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router
});
```

this is my router.js file code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

import firstPage from './components/pages/myFirstVuePage'
import newRoutePage from './components/pages/newRoutePage'

const routes = [
{
    path:'/my-new-vue-router',
    component: firstPage
},
{
    path:'/new-router',
    component: newRoutePage
}
]

export default  new Router({
mode:'history',
routes
})
```

this is my vue file code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>this is my first vue page</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "myFirstVuePage.vue"
}
</script>
```

this is mainApp.vue file code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>this is the first component</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "mainApp.vue"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

this is my welcome.blade.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>this the body</h1>
<div id="app">
    <mainapp></mainapp>
</div>
</body>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</html>
```

the output is just this one:

"this the body
this is the first component"

Comment: Either your component isn't being loaded correctly or the route isn't being triggered. The fact that you see content from the `<mainApp>` component proves Laravel and Vue are doing what they should. Are there any errors in the console? Have you used the Vue developer tools to debug (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en)?

Comment: there is not any error in the console

Comment: yes I am using these tools,

Answer (score 0):

Remove  . vue extension components name property value
name: "myFirstVuePage"
Also in main.vue file
name: "mainApp"

Comment: compiled, but the problem still remains